# jQuery replace integer globally in html var

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace a number globally in my HTML string by regex but it only replaces the number when it's not attached to an attribute.

e.g. I want to replace the number 123 globally. The problem in this example is that only the number in the value has been changed and not the number between the brackets.

```
var oldId = 123;
var newId = 1234;

<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="123">
<input type="radio"  name="field_name[123]" class="id_123">

$('.settings').replace(/oldId/g, newId);
```

Current result

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="1234"> <-- changed
<input type="radio"  name="field_name[123]" class="id_123"> <--- not changed
```

I guess I need to modify my regex a somehow?

Comment: The code that you have posted will throw a `TypeError` as jQuery objects do no have `replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()`, `g` flag at `RegExp` to replace `.outerHTML` of elements where `name` attribute includes `"field_name"`

```js
var oldId = 123;
var newId = 1234;

$("input[name*=field_name]").each(function(i, el) {
  el.outerHTML = el.outerHTML.replace(new RegExp(oldId, "g"), newId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="123">
<input type="radio" name="field_name[123]" class="id_123">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Took the '.replace(new RegExp(oldId, "g"), newId)'' part of your code and this did the trick. Many thanks! =)